# Django - Form does not save

Tags: python, django, forms, listview, validationerror

I'm making a website that shows events using a ListView and each event has a sign up form.

Form validation errors all show up, but upon successful submission of the form, it just brings me to the success page and the form does not get saved into the database.

When I submit the form via admin and not the form, it gives me an error:
NameError at /admin/home/signups/add/
global name 'fullname' is not defined with traceback to: instance.fullname = fullname in forms.py.

Another error if I completely remove that line is: 
NameError at /admin/home/signups/add/
global name 'request' is not defined with traceback to instance.ip = get_ip(request) in forms.py.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUps, Hours, Events
import datetime
from ipware.ip import get_ip

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fullname = forms.CharField(label="Full name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full name', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = SignUps
        fields = ['eventname','fullname','ip']

    def clean_fullname(self):
        fullname = self.cleaned_data.get('fullname').title()
        eventname = self.cleaned_data.get('eventname')
        try:
            name = Hours.objects.get(fullname=fullname)
        except Hours.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid Key Club member's full name as displayed in the hours page.")
        try:
            name = SignUps.objects.get(fullname=fullname)
        except SignUps.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                numOfSignUps = SignUps.objects.filter(eventname=eventname).count()
            except SignUps.DoesNotExist:
                numOfSignUps = 0
            try:
                event = Events.objects.get(name=eventname)
            except Events.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Something went wrong. This event does not exist.")
            try:
                ifFull = Events.objects.filter(name=eventname).get(maximum__gt=numOfSignUps)
            except Events.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("The maximum number of attendees has already been reached.")
            try:
                date = Events.objects.filter(name=eventname).get(date=datetime.date.today())
            except Events.DoesNotExist:
                return fullname
            raise forms.ValidationError("It is too late to sign up for this event.")
        raise forms.ValidationError("This member is already signed up.")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance =  super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.fullname = fullname
        instance.ip = get_ip(request)
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

events/index.html main body:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:75px;">

    {% block content %}

    {% for announcements in announcement %}
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
      <h4 class="alert-heading">{{ announcements.announcementname }}</h4>
      <p style="margin:0 0;">{{ announcements.announcement | safe | linebreaksbr | urlize }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for events in events_list %}
    <div id="checkIn" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">OCC Check-Ins</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passcode" placeholder="Passcode" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button></div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <div class="card card-block col-sm-6" style="display:inline-block;">
      <div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
        <a href="#" style="color:black;" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><h5><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h5></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton" style="right:0;left:auto;">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h4 class="card-title">{{ events.name }}</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Description: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.description }}</span><br>Where: <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/{{ events.location }}" class="text-muted">{{ events.location }}</a><br>When: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.date|date:"D, M d, Y" }}</span><br>Time: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.time|time:"P" }}</span><br>Max: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.maximum }}</span><br>Hours: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.hours }}</span><br>Check in with: <span class="text-muted">{{ events.occ }}</span></p>
      <h4 class="card-text" style="margin-top:-6px;margin-bottom:8px;"><a href="#" style="color:black; text-decoration:none;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#checkIn"><i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></i> OCC Check-Ins</a></h4>
      <form action="/events/" class="form" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="id_eventname" maxlength="125" name="eventname" type="hidden" value="{{ events.name }}">
          {{ form.fullname }}
          {{ form.fullname.errors }}
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}

  </div>
```

success.html is just a blank HTML page that says "success":

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:75px;">
    Success
  </div>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from home.models import Events, Announcement, Hours, SignUps
from django import forms
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View
from ipware.ip import get_ip
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about/index.html')

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'events/success.html')

class EventsDisplay(ListView, FormView):
    template_name='events/index.html'
    context_object_name = "events_list"
    queryset = Events.objects.all().order_by("date")
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = "/events/success"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        context = super(EventsDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['announcement'] = Announcement.objects.all().order_by("-datetime")
        context['signup'] = SignUps.objects.all().order_by("fullname")
        return context

class HoursList(ListView):
    template_name = 'hours/index.html'
    context_object_name = "hours_list"
    queryset = Hours.objects.all().order_by("fullname")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HoursList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['announcement'] = Announcement.objects.all().order_by("-datetime")
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from views import EventsDisplay, HoursList
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^events/$', EventsDisplay.as_view()),
    url(r'^events/success$', views.success, name='success'),
    url(r'^hours/$', HoursList.as_view()),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after reviewing the code a fair bit, I believe there could be a lot more refactoring done here.

Firstly, I don't see the point of mixing up the class based views and a function based view. These standard `get` and `post` requests can be done like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from home.models import Events, Announcement, Hours, SignUps
from django import forms
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View
from ipware.ip import get_ip
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class EventsDisplay(ListView, FormView):
    template_name='events/index.html'
    context_object_name = "events_list"
    queryset = Events.objects.all().order_by("date")
    form_class = SignUpForm 
    success_url = "events/success.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventsDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['announcement'] = Announcement.objects.all().order_by("-datetime")
        # No need to insert 'form' as Django  takes care of that
        # by utilising self.form_class
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form): 
        instance = form.save(commit=False) instance.save() 
        return super(EventsDisplay, self).form_valid(form)
```

Basically, I have merged your code into a single class based view that inherits from `ListView` (for your `get` requests) and `FormView` (for your `post` requests).

As a result of this change in your views, your `urls` should now become:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from views import EventsList, HoursList
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^events/$', EventsDisplay.as_view()),
    url(r'^hours/$', HoursList.as_view()),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Finally, if you have to "prod" your model variables before saving (eg. insert ip address), you should place this kind of code within the form like this:

```
from django import forms
from .models import SignUps, Hours, Events
import datetime
from ipware.ip import get_ip
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fullname = forms.CharField(label="Full name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Full name', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = SignUps
        fields = ['eventname','fullname','ip']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_fullname(self):
        ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance =  super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.fullname = fullname
        instance.ip = get_ip(self.request)
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: When I submit the form it gives me an error: AttributeError at /events/
'EventsDisplay' object has no attribute 'object_list'. Traceback goes to: context = super(EventsDisplay, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) in views.py

Comment: Instead of using `object_list` in your html code, now use `events_list`. The `context_object_name` allows you to use a more specific name in the templates rather than using a general and meaningless name like `object_list`.

Comment: I've fixed it by adding: self.object_list = self.get_queryset() to get_context_data. The form validation works and errors show up; however, upon success, the values aren't being saved to the database; it only brings me to the success page.

Comment: Please see edited answer - i made a small mistake in my return statement when saving. It should be `return instance` not `return commit`

Comment: Same thing still occurs. Form validation works but upon successful submission, it still does not save it to the database. I've updated my original question to reflect my current code and files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129740/discussion-between-leo-shao-and-apoorv-kansal).

Comment: I've fixed my issue by adding `def form_valid(self, form):

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        instance.save()

        return super(EventsDisplay, self).form_valid(form)` to my class `EventsDisplay(ListView, FormView)`, but I still don't know how to add the user's IP address because it's not a request so I can't simply use instance.ip = get_ip(request). I've posted a separate question regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit a validation error in `SignUpForm`, your `SignUp(request)` function sure does pick up the errors in the `form` object but you are returning a different page (`events/success.html`) from what your `GET` returns (`events/index.html`).

I am assuming that `events/success.html` does not have the same html code you have supplied which seems to be for `events/index.html`.

Your `SignUp(request)` function should look like this:

```
def SignUp(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            fullname = form.cleaned_data.get("fullname")
            instance.fullname = fullname
            instance.ip = get_ip(request)
            instance.save()
        else: # INVALID FORM - WE HAVE VALIDATION ERRORS SO RETURN SAME PAGE.
            return render(request, "events/index.html", {"form": form})

    else:
        form = SignUpForm
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "events/success.html", context)
```

Comment: I just changed it to events/index.html but when I do this the elements of the ListView do not show up so my index.html basically only shows the navbar and the footer.

Comment: Can your provide both your index and success html files?

Comment: I've just updated the question to include the full body of the index.html excluding navbar and footer. My success.html page is blank and simply says "success."

Comment: Please see updates - I am just saying to return the SAME page `events/index.html` only when you get validation errors.

Comment: I've added it but everything in the {% block content %} and {% for %} loops still do not show up. It loads the events page but only with the navbar and the footer.